# Multi-language with domain name specific doesn't work

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, redirection

I am working on a multi-language website. I am setting content in both English and French.

When I use **path prefix** as my detection method, it works fine, like poc-local.com and poc-local.com/fr. When I use **domain** as my detection method, it doesn't work, like fr.poc-local.com.

I am getting a 302 error, and "the page isn't redirecting properly" error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi ,I found this link https://www.drupal.org/node/1735762. I am new to drupal and how to apply these patches???

Comment: elan, the patch provided there is for Drupal 6 version, so it won't work for you. [see picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/89Bc0.jpg)

Comment: Ok Ok I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this.

I have installed global redirect module and now it's working.

https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect

But Now I am having another one problem.My language Switcher block is not working.When I switching from one language to another language the recently switched language url displaying for all languages...